# Did the commander see Mark just before the take off?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-martian

At the beginning of "The Martian", did the commander see Mark before she was getting into the ship?

Comment: You mean right at the start? They did not know about such a storm incoming

Comment: they first come to ship during storm and they get out.

Comment: Because a storm was coming that was going to destroy their only space vehicle (the ship). If they lost it, they would all be in the same boat as Watney (they would die for one reason or another).

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the asker means the hab when they say "ship".

Comment: This question should not be re-opened upon further edits, as it is NOTHING like the original question was responded to.  Better to just ask a new question, at this point.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson why the major question change?

Answer (score 3):

They don't get out of the ship.

They see the storm is coming, and decide they have to abort the rest of the mission and leave for the safety of all.  What they leave is the habitat/quarters/installation, and they go TO the ship so they can leave.

It would be the Earth equivalent of a hurricane coming, so you leave your house to get into your car, parked in the driveway, so you can drive to safety.

Comment: I think the OP may have mistook the Hab for a ship.

Comment: @Liesmith - agreed.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet or, the OP may be asking why the crew went to the Hab instead of leaving immediately once they were aware of the storm.

Comment: @cst1992 - Please note the date of my answer vs the date of the latest question-edit.  The original wording of the question: "I don't get why everyone gets out from ship while it was Storm outside. what was their intention for going out?"

Answer (score 2):

The Mars expedition team has been on Mars for about a month now, after ~9 months of travel to Mars. They are in the middle of routine research tasks, collecting data and samples for science. They are living, camping really,  in the HAB, a habitat built on Mars. Their main spaceship is in orbit, and the Mars Descent Vehicle (MDV) was a one way ship. The ship they get in is the Mars Ascent Vehicle,  the MAV, also a one trick pony.

Mars has regular dust storms, but the one that hit was SO OVERPOWERED that they had to leave as an emergency.

They left the HAB, a makeshift building, for the MAV because otherwise they would die or get stranded on Mars because of the storm.